# How to send data from <option> to another page and search database using React

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to send the name of an area (selected in a ) to another page for it to search the database to find any matches and display some of its details. (The  is populated by the JSON, so they all have one entry of each option)

HomePage.js

```
class Search extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchString: "",
            house_data: [],
            selectedArea: "",
        };
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleSelect(eve) {
        this.setState({selectedArea: eve.target.value});
        console.log(eve.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        let _data = this.state.house_data;

        return (
            <div>
                <select onChange={this.handleSelect} >
                    <option selected disabled>Select an Area</option>
                    
                        {_data.map((house) => {
                            return (
                                <option>
                                    {house.area}
                                </option>
                            );
                        })}
                </select>
                <button>
                    <Link
                        key={this.state.selectedArea}
                        to={`/search/${this.state.selectedArea}`}
                    >Search
                    </Link>
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

It is getting the object when I log `props.match.params`, but when I put it in a variable and use that to search, it can no longer find anything, and just returns 'undefined' when I know that there is a property that has that area.

SearchPage.js

```
export function SearchPage(props) {
    let { theArea } = props.match.params;
    const aHouseThatMatches = data.find((house) => house.area === theArea);
    console.log(aHouseThatMatches); //LOGS 'UNDEFINED'
    console.log(props.match.params); //LOGS Object { area: "Bournemouth" } which is correct, but it cannot find it in 'aHouseThatMatches'
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (aHouseThatMatches) {
            document.title = `${aHouseThatMatches.text}`;
        } else {
            document.title = "No houses in this area";
        }
    }, []);

    if (aHouseThatMatches) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{aHouseThatMatches.text}</h1>
                <h1>{theArea}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>There are no properties in this area</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is **data** defined in your SearchPage.js ? Also you cannot destructure props.match.params to { theArea } , as from your logs the correct key is area. So obviously it'll come undefined. It should be destructured as let { area } = props.params.match;

Comment: @AbhishekSharma that was it, thank you so much!! It was changing theArea to area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructure your props.match.params correctly.
As seen in yours logs it should be

`let { area } = props.match.params`